# Cannot download maps

Tags: 8.1, maps, here, nokia-lumia-530

I want to download maps for my region (Russia), but when I start to download maps, I get this error:

> We can't reach the maps library at the moment. Make sure flight mode is turned off and check your mobile date or wifi connection then try again.

I'm using my home wifi. I am able to open the sites http://here.com and http://131.228.152.4.

How can I fix this? I've tried removing map files, as well as rebooting my smartphone.

Comment: Have you tried doing a soft reset? Also check if your date and time are set correctly for your region.

Comment: @Thomas, data and time are set correctly (I set my timezone). Also, I have tried to set automatically date/time. It did not help me.
I did not do a soft reset.

Comment: then go ahead and try it (just hold down the power and volume down buttons for ~10 seconds). Your data wont be lost, you just need to set date and time afterwards.

Comment: @Thomas, android and ios are able to restore settings and contacts from cloud backup. Does windows phone have such stuff?

Comment: yes this is possible since Windows Phone 8.1 I guess. but youll only need to do this when doing a hard reset, not when doing a soft reset. Check http://www.windowscentral.com/how-to-back-up-settings-windows-phone-81

Comment: @Thomas, unfortunately, soft reset does not work for me.

Comment: then the only thing I can recommend is doing a hard reset and hope that this will fix it.

Comment: @Thomas, ok, I will think about it. Thank you.